# Как динамически создать CheckBox?

Tags: android, activity, checkbox

Как динамически сделать СheckBox? (в MainActivity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задайте `id` лэйауту:

```
<LinearLayout   
android:id="@+id/check_add_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/feedbackPlansCheckBoxLL"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Инициализируйте:

```
LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.check_add_layout);
```

Создайте `CheckBox`:

```
CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(this);
checkBox.setId(id);
checkBox.setText("text");
```

Задайте параметры:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams checkParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
checkParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
checkParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
```

И добавьте его:

```
parentLayout.addView(checkBox, checkParams);
```